# Get value from database and put it into textbox

Tags: c#, mysql, class, connection

I totally new at programming and i am learning about, classes, methods connection with mysql.

So i have a class called `take` and i have a method to get last value from my database table.

```
namespace Budget
{
    class take
    {
        private MySqlConnection connection;
        private string datasource;
        private string port;
        private string username;
        private string password;
        public take()
        {
            Initialize();
        }
        private void Initialize()
        {
            datasource = "localhost";
            port = "3306";
            username = "root";
            password = "root";
            string connectionString;
            connectionString = "DATASOURCE=" + datasource + ";" + "PORT=" + port + ";" + "USERNAME=" + username + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";

            connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        }
        private bool OpenConnection()
        {
            connection.Open();
            return true;
        }
        private bool CloseConnection()
        {
            connection.Close();
            return true;
        }
        public decimal budget()
        {
            string query =
              @"SELECT balance 
              FROM history 
              ORDER BY id DESC 
              LIMIT 1 ";
            if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
            {
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
                using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (reader.Read())
                        return Convert.ToDecimal(reader.GetValue(0));
                    else
                        return 0m;
                }
            }
            else
                return 0m;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to put that value in my main Form TextBox. But when i write in main main Form

```
 take.balance();
```

> Warning Warning    1   Field `Budget.Form1.take` is never assigned to, and will always have its default value `null`

So the question is, how i can put that value from database to my main Form textbox?

Comment: ...you need to instantiate `take`. Usually by writing `take = new Take()`

Comment: can you show the `take` class ? :) You can make it `static` for such simple operations :)

Comment: @meorfi Looks like they're using a connection-object that's a field, so that just opens up a whole other can of worms. But yes. One could make it static.

Comment: ok, i edited with full class `take`